# ¿En donde se encontraría el fallo en este ejercicio de listas en C?

Tags: c

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio de listas simples, en el que debo cargar desde un fichero los datos a una lista y desde otro a otra, lo que es cargar creo que funciona correctamente, pero en las otras funciones no encuentro cual puede ser el fallo, alguien podría ayudarme y decirme donde esta el fallo en el codigo?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NAME "pokedex" //Definimos el nombre del archivo principal pokedex


struct PokemonPokedex{
 int numero; //numero en la Pokedex
 char nombre[20]; //nombre del Pokemon
 char tipo[20]; //tipo del Pokemon
 int dificultad; //dificultad para capturarlo
 int vistos; // veces que se ha visto el Pokemon
 int capturados; //Pokemons que han sido capturados
};

struct ListaPokedex{
 int numero; //numero en la Pokedex
 char nombre[20]; //nombre del Pokemon
 char tipo[20]; //tipo del Pokemon
 int dificultad; //dificultad para capturarlo
 int vistos; // veces que se ha visto el Pokemon
 int capturados; //Pokemons que han sido capturados
 struct ListaPokedex *sig;
};
struct ListaEquipo
{
 int numero; //numero en la Pokedex
 char nombre[20]; //nombre del Pokemon
 char tipo[20]; //tipo del Pokemon
 int nivel; //nivel del pokemon
 struct PokemonEquipo *sig;
};

struct PokemonEquipo
{
 int numero; //numero en la Pokedex
 char nombre[20]; //nombre del Pokemon
 char tipo[20]; //tipo del Pokemon
 int nivel; //nivel del pokemon
};

void captura(struct ListaPokedex **primero);
void visPokedex(struct ListaPokedex **primero);
void visEquipo(struct ListaEquipo **primero);
int menu();
void cargarDatosPokedex(struct ListaPokedex **primero);
void savePokedex(struct ListaPokedex **primero);
void cargarDatosEquipo(struct ListaEquipo **primero);
void saveEquipo(struct ListaEquipo **primero);
// MAIN //

int main(){
    struct ListaPokedex *pokedex;
    struct ListaEquipo *equipo;

    pokedex=NULL;
    equipo=NULL;
    cargarDatosPokedex(&pokedex);

    cargarDatosEquipo(&equipo);

    srand(time(NULL));
    int opc; 

    do{
        opc=menu();

        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                captura(&pokedex);
                break;
            case 2:
                visEquipo(&equipo);
                break;
            case 3:
                visPokedex(&pokedex);
                break;
            case 4:
                saveEquipo(&equipo);
                savePokedex(&pokedex);
                printf("Guardando...No apagues la consola.\n Has guardado el juego.\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(opc!=4);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



// FUNCIONES //



void cargarDatosPokedex(struct ListaPokedex **primero){
    FILE *f;
    struct ListaPokedex *recorre, *temp;
    struct PokemonPokedex pokedex;


    temp = (struct ListaPokedex*) malloc(sizeof(struct ListaPokedex));

    f=fopen(NAME,"rb");

    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error al cargar los datos.\n");
        return;
    }   

    while(fread(&pokedex, sizeof(struct PokemonPokedex),1,f)){

        temp->numero=pokedex.numero;
        strcpy(temp->nombre,pokedex.nombre );
        strcpy(temp->tipo, pokedex.tipo);
        temp->dificultad=pokedex.dificultad;
        temp->vistos=pokedex.vistos;
        temp->capturados=pokedex.capturados;
        temp->sig=NULL;

        if(*primero==NULL){
            *primero=temp;

        }
        else{
            recorre=*primero;
            while(recorre->sig!=NULL){
                recorre=recorre->sig;
            }
            recorre->sig=temp;
        }
    }
}

void savePokedex(struct ListaPokedex **primero){
    FILE *f;
    struct ListaPokedex *recorre;
    struct PokemonPokedex pokedex;

    f=fopen(NAME, "wb");
    recorre=*primero;
    while(recorre!=NULL){
        pokedex.numero=recorre->numero;
        strcpy(pokedex.nombre, recorre->nombre);
        strcpy(pokedex.tipo, recorre->tipo);
        pokedex.dificultad=recorre->dificultad;
        pokedex.vistos=recorre->vistos;
        pokedex.capturados=recorre->capturados;
        recorre=recorre->sig;
        fwrite(&pokedex, sizeof(struct PokemonPokedex),1,f);
    }
}

void cargarDatosEquipo(struct ListaEquipo **primero){
    FILE *f;
    struct ListaEquipo *temp, *recorre;
    struct PokemonEquipo equipo;


    temp = (struct ListaEquipo*) malloc(sizeof(struct ListaEquipo));

    f=fopen("equipo","rb");

    if(f==NULL){

        return;
    }   

    while(fread(&equipo, sizeof(struct PokemonEquipo),1,f)){
        temp->numero=equipo.numero;
        strcpy(temp->nombre,equipo.nombre );
        strcpy(temp->tipo, equipo.tipo);
        temp->nivel=equipo.nivel;
        temp->sig=NULL;

        if(*primero==NULL){
            *primero=temp;

        }
        else{

            recorre=*primero;
            while(recorre->sig!=NULL){
                recorre=recorre->sig;
            }
            recorre->sig=temp;
        }

    }
}

void saveEquipo(struct ListaEquipo **primero){
    FILE *f;
    struct ListaEquipo *recorre;
    struct PokemonEquipo pokedex;

    f=fopen(NAME, "wb");
    recorre=*primero;
    while(recorre!=NULL){
        pokedex.numero=recorre->numero;
        strcpy(pokedex.nombre, recorre->nombre);
        strcpy(pokedex.tipo, recorre->tipo);
        pokedex.nivel=recorre->nivel;
        recorre=recorre->sig;
        fwrite(&pokedex, sizeof(struct PokemonPokedex),1,f);
    }
}
//La funcion captura es  utilizada para el apartado uno. En la cual generaremos un pokemon aleatorio y veremos si somos capaces o no de capturarlo.
void captura(struct ListaPokedex **primero){
    struct PokemonPokedex pokedex;
    struct ListaPokedex *recorre;
    struct ListaEquipo *temp, *recorreEquip=*primero, *anterior=NULL;
    recorre=*primero;
    FILE *f;
    int nPokemon, nNivel, nCapturar;
    int i;
    int aux=0;

    nPokemon=rand() %151; //Generamos un numero de la pokedex aleatorio del 0 al 150.
    nNivel=rand() %100+1; //Generamos un nivel aleatorio para el pokemon anterior.
    nCapturar=0;

    f=fopen(NAME, "rb"); //Abrimos el fichero pokedex en modo lectura/escritura porque necesitamos modificar el numero de veces visto y capturado dicho pokemon.
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo.\n"); //Hacemos una comprobacion para ver si el fichero existe.
        return;
    }

    while(recorre->numero!=nPokemon){ //Creamos un bucle para localizar al pokemon buscado que en caso de que el numero generado por la funcion rand y el de la pokedex asigne al valor posicion
                                       //donde se encuentra el pokemon buscado.
        recorre=recorre->sig;

    }



    printf("Se va a intentar capturar %s\n", recorre->nombre);

    for(i=0;i<3&&nCapturar<recorre->dificultad;i++){  // Este bucle es para ver si capturamos o no al pokemon para ello vamos a hacer un bucle que se repita 3 veces mientras el poder de la pokeball sea inferior al del pokemon
        printf("Se va a lanzar una pokeball\n");
        nCapturar=rand()%101; //Se asigna un valor aleatorio al poder de captura.
        printf("Se tiene %d de poder y la dificultad de ese pokemon es de %d\n", nCapturar, pokedex.dificultad);
        if(nCapturar>recorre->dificultad){//Si el poder de captura es superior al del pokemon se finaliza el bucle y se añade uno al numero de pokemons capturado.
            recorre->capturados++;
            aux++;
            printf("El pokemon %s ha sido capturado!\n", recorre->nombre);
        }
    }

    recorre->vistos++; //Independientemente de si ha escapado o le hemos atrapado tenemos que aumentar el numero de pokemons vistos.
    if(aux==0){//Si aux es diferente de 0 significa que lo hemos capturado
        printf("El pokemon ha huido.\n"); 
    }
    else{//Si no copiamos los datos necesarios del fichero pokedex al fichero equipo.
        temp->numero=recorre->numero;
        temp->nivel=nNivel;
        strcpy(temp->nombre,recorre->nombre);
        strcpy(temp->tipo, recorre->tipo);
        while(recorre->dificultad>temp->nivel&&recorre!=NULL){
            anterior=recorre;
            recorre=recorre->sig;
        }
        if(anterior==NULL){
            temp->sig=*primero;
            *primero=temp;
        }
        else{
            anterior->sig=temp;
            temp->sig=recorre;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

}


//Esta funcion visualiza la pokedex, muestra los pokemon vistos y en caso de que lo hayamos capturado visualizara tambien su tipo.
void visPokedex(struct ListaPokedex **primero){
    struct ListaPokedex *recorre;

    recorre=*primero;
    while(recorre!=NULL){ //Creamos un bucle que vaya leyendo todo el fichero y aquellos pokemon los cuales hayamos vistos se visualizaran.
        if(recorre->vistos>0){
            printf("+--------------------------------------+\n");
            printf("| %d                    %s             \n", recorre->capturados, recorre->nombre);
            if(recorre->capturados==0){ //Si no hemos capturado dicho pokemon no se visualizara su tipo.
            printf("| Tipo:                 ----------     \n");
            }
            else{
            printf("| Tipo:            %s                  \n", recorre->tipo);
            }
            printf("| Vistos: %d         Capturados: %d    \n", recorre->vistos, recorre->capturados);
            printf("+--------------------------------------+\n");
        }
        recorre=recorre->sig;
    }


}



//Esta funcion visualiza los pokemon que hemos capturado.
void visEquipo(struct ListaEquipo **primero){
    struct ListaEquipo *equipo;

    equipo=*primero;
    while(equipo!=NULL){
        printf("+--------------------------------------+\n");
        printf("| %d                    %s             \n", equipo->numero, equipo->nombre);
        printf("| Nivel: %d                            \n", equipo->nivel); 
        printf("| Tipo:            %s                  \n", equipo->tipo);
        printf("+--------------------------------------+\n");
        equipo=equipo->sig;
    }


}

int menu(){
    int opc;

    do{
        printf("Menu: \n");
        printf("1. Capturar.\n");
        printf("2. Ver equipo.\n");
        printf("3. Ver pokedex.\n");
        printf("4. Salir.\n");
        scanf("%d", &opc);
    }while(opc<1||opc>4);
    return opc;

}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que tiene un fallo? ¿no compila? ¿se "rompe" al ejecutar? ¿no hace lo que esperabas? Describe qué comportamiento esperabas y cuál tiene en realidad

Comment: En la función captura se queda parado y no salta ni que ha dejado de funcionar ni nada, en visualizar pasa lo mismo

Comment: El código es demasiado largo para que yo pueda revisarlo en profundidad. Además, al carecer de los ficheros de datos no puedo probar a ejecutarlo. No obstante sí puedo decirte que la compilación arroja unos cuantos warnings de tipos de puntero incompatible (por ejemplo, asignas a un puntero `ListaEquipo*` un valor de tipo `PokemonEquipo*`, y viceversa. Como mínimo, te sugiero revisar con cuidado esa lista de _warnings_ y tratar de repararlos todos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Donde por ejemplo hago eso? Es que llevo un tiempo intentando arreglar los warnings y nada!

Comment: Pues por ejemplo, la estructura `ListaEquipo`, entiendo que es para crear una lista enlazada. En ese caso, su campo `sig` debe ser de tipo `ListaEquipo` también, pues apunta al siguiente elemento de la lista que será del mismo tipo. En cambio has hecho que sea un puntero a `PokemonEquipo`, que es una estructura similar pero que no tiene campo `sig`, entonces... cuando en la línea 184 haces `recorre=recorre->sig` no funcionará correctamente puesto que una vez estas en el siguiente elemento de la lista `recorre` ya no tiene `sig`.

Comment: No sé que IDE usas para compilar, pero la mayoría de ellos te muestran los avisos en algún tipo de panel y te permiten ir a la línea donde sucede. En mi caso, el primer _warning_ ocurre en la línea 184 antes mecionada, aunque como ves, la causa está mucho antes, en la declaración de la estructura. Te recomiendo que revises cada aviso tratando de comprenderlo y si en alguno tienes dificultades, edites esta pregunta añadiendo qué línea en concreto te da un aviso que no entiendes.

Comment: Vale vale muchas gracias!!!!!